# Calling Value From another macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform which opens one of a list of worksheets. I want to create a macro that recognises the last sheet opened by the userform and then runs data validation based on data types in the sheet.

How can I reference the sheet opened so that it can be called later my the validation macro?

All help gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 1):

You need to "remember" it in a *Public* variable.

In a Standard Module, near the top of that module, include:

```
Public LastSheet As Worksheet
```

and in the UserForm, code like:

```
Sub WithinUserForm()
    Dim x As String
    x = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="pick a worksheet", Type:=2)
    Sheets(x).Select
    Set LastSheet = ActiveSheet
End Sub
```

Finally within the DV macro:

```
Sub MacroForDV()
    LastSheet.Select
End Sub
```